# Give an example of a series of functions on the interval [0, 1] that converges pointwise but does not converge uniformly on any subinterval

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

A series of functions that would work is in need.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A *series* of functions or *sequence* of functions?

Comment: Series of functions!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f_n(x) = 1$ if $x = a/2^n$ where $a$ is an odd integer, $0$ otherwise.

Comment: This is very clever.

Comment: Why do you require $a$ to be an odd integer, and not just an integer?

Comment: To make it work both for the sequence $f_n(x)$ and the series $\sum_n f_n(x)$.